# Loading an image in a Blazor Client-side App

Tags: c#, blazor, embedded-resource, system.drawing

I have a Blazor client-side app, and I'm trying to load an embedded image:

```
var stream = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream("myimg.jpg");

//System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(null);
//var bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
```

The problem that I have is that neither of the commented code lines can be used in a Blazor app (they won't work in the browser).  Is there a way around this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image?

Comment: I want to crop it, and then display to the screen

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Drawing.Graphics` namespace is not part of .NET Core 3.1 or NET 5.

It was originally in .NET Framework (possibly where you got example code from) -- this was because it was based on Windows GDI system, and .NET Core is cross-platform and cannot rely on GDI being present (e.g. Mac/Linux).

You can use some of the libraries as there is a NUGET package that provides this functionality: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common

However it's not always plug-and-go: there may be platform specific requirements, see https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-do-you-use-systemdrawing-in-net-core for more help.

Comment: It's actually System.Drawing.Common that I'm using. I get a warning telling me that it's not supported on 'browser'